# STM32F411RCT6 not talking to LCD panel - I2C and HAL library

Tags: i2c, lcd, stm32f4, stm32cubemx

I have an MCU chip STM32F411RCT6 and I am using stm32cube software to generate HAL library based code.

I have to establish communication between the MCU and LCD panel which is NHD-C0220BIZ-FS(RGB)-FBW-3VM using I2C, while MCU is the master.

C code is given either in the data sheet of the LCD or I found somewhere, below is the code:

```
/* Initializes the LCD panel. */
void init_LCD(void) {
    I2C_Start();

    I2C_out( 0x78 );    // Slave address of the LCD panel.
    I2C_out( 0x00 );    // Control byte: all following bytes are commands.
    I2C_out( 0x38 );    // 8-bit bus, 2-line display, normal instruction mode.
    delay( 10 );

    I2C_out( 0x39 );    // 8-bit bus, 2-line display, extension instruction mode.
    delay( 10 );

    I2C_out( 0x14 );    // Bias set to 1/5.
    I2C_out( 0x78 );    // Contrast set.
    I2C_out( 0x5E );    // Icon display on, booster on, contrast set.
    I2C_out( 0x6D );    // Follower circuit on, amplifier=1?
    I2C_out( 0x0C );    // Display on, cursor off.
    I2C_out( 0x01 );    // Clear display.
    I2C_out( 0x06 );    // Entry mode set to cursor-moves-right.
    delay( 10 );

    I2C_Stop();
}

/* Writes a 10-char string to the RAM of the LCD. */
void show( unsigned char *text ) {
    int n;

    I2C_Start();

    I2C_out( 0x78 ); // Slave address of panel.
    I2C_out( 0x40 ); // Control byte: data bytes follow, data is RAM data.

    for( n = 0; n < 10; n++ ) {
        I2C_out( *text );
        text++;
    }

    I2C_Stop();
}

void main(void) {
    int i;

    init_LCD();

    show("HelloWorld");

    while(1)
    {}
}
```

I used HAL_I2C_Master_Trasmit() to transmit ten bytes at once like in the function init_LCD() and eleven bytes at once as in show() function. There is no I2C_Start() and I2C_Stop() functions in HAL library.
The slave address is 0x78, as I am writing to the LCD unlike reading, I guess, I donot have to change this address.

I am currently getting HAL_ERROR or 1 value as the return value of the HAL_I2C_Master_Trasmit() function.

If possible, could you sort of convert this code in HAL I2C.

Comment: What is required here is pretty run-of-the-mill embedded debugging. Start single stepping through the code and see where the HAL_ERROR is produced. That might lead to a simple fix, otherwise you just need to keep digging all the way to a scope on the I2C lines until you locate the issue. Welcome to the fun world of embedded software!

Comment: Also have a read up on the I2C. The Start and Stop handling is very important, and different libraries/devices manage it in different ways.

Comment: Show us how you use the `HAL_I2C_Master_Trasmit()` your current code tells us nothing. The logic is hidden...

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to shift your slave address by 1 bit.

```
I2C_out( 0x78 << 1 );    // Slave address of the LCD panel.
```

Arduino does this automatically, but HAL does not.

Comment: This might be the problem. The correct code should look like this with HAL: `HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, (0x78 << 1), dataBuffer, bufferLength, 10000);`